# Ruby on Rails: how do I add an HTML class parameter to this link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% link_to :controller => :menu_bars, :action => :select do %>
    <div class="action_box right">
        Manage Menu Bars
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I've never been able to figure out the syntax for the documentation... so... here I am.

I want it to render something like `<a ... class="myclass">`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% link_to({:controller => :menu_bars, :action => :select}, :class => "myclass") do %>
    <div class="action_box right">
        Manage Menu Bars
    </div>
<% end %>


<a href="/countries/new" class="myclass">    
  <div class="action_box right">
    Manage Menu Bars
  </div>
</a>
```